# как изменить код так, чтобы вместо While было for , и при переводе с 10 в 2 систему использовалось не вычитание а деление?

Tags: c, массивы, функции, binary, системы-счисления

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>





void encode_char(const char character, bool bits[8]){   
int number[] = {128 , 64 , 32 , 16 ,8 ,4 ,2 ,1};
 float x = 0;
 float y = character;
int i = 0;
while(i != 8){
  x = y;
  y = y - number[i];`перевод из 10 в 2 с помощью вычитания`
  if(y < 0){
    bits[i] = false;
    y = x;
  }
  else if(y >= 0){
    bits[i] = true;
  }
  i = i + 1;
}
}


int main() {
bool bits1[8];
encode_char('A', bits1);
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    printf("%d", bits1[i]);
}
printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include  <limits.h>
#include  <stdbool.h>

void encode_char(unsigned char character, bool bits[CHAR_BIT]) {   
    for (int i = CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        bits[i] = character % 2 != 0;
        character /= 2;
    }
}
```

[Тест](https://rextester.com/WYNU58486)